# Restricting the address space of a pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have a theoretical question. I've recently found myself thinking about the mechanics of smart pointers, and (largely inspired by [this thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=31626508)) how they can be optimized (or, at least, how we can trade-off performance with addressable space).

To my understanding, the simplest possible smart pointer refers to two values: an address, and a static reference count (also an address).

```
template<typename T> class ptr {
private: 
    T* ptr; 
    int* ref; 
    // ... etc.
};
```

**Question:** Is there a way to fit both pointers within one 64 bit address space, and what would the implications be for both performance and addressable memory space?

**My thoughts:** The smart pointer then fits in a single register on a 64 bit machine, which (I imagine) would make it have similar qualities to a raw pointer. As we have two pointers, I suppose that our memory space would be limited to 2^32? I'm not sure what the implications of that would be, or if it is possible within a 64 bit space (would managing this be a nightmare?).

Comment: No, that's not possible using legal ways. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: It is a theoretical question (my own curiosity). If it isn't possible using legal ways, could you elaborate why?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It is probably possible relying on implementation-defined behavior with pointer/integer conversions on at least certain systems without invoking UB.

Comment: @ck4e My intuition is that, even if you manage to do this, that there won't be any performance gain. On the contrary, extracting the pointers all the time will be costly. The number of pointers will not affect how the class is passed (registers vs stack) btw. It can't be passed in registers by-value anyway, because it has a non-trivial destructor.

Comment: _"the simplest possible smart pointer refers to two values: an address, and a static reference count"_ - No, the simplest possible smart pointer doesn't have a reference count. See `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: @TedLyngmo you may be correct, but you appear to have missed the intent of this question.

Comment: You can store both pointer and refcount separately and have your smart pointer be a pointer to that structure.

Comment: @ck4e No, I understand exactly what you are asking but since you stated what your understanding of what the simplest possible smart pointer is, and it is wrong, I thought that you might want to know that.

Comment: @ck4e *"appear to have missed the intent of this question"* -- no, missing the point would be something an answer might do. A comment is not an answer (at least, a comment is supposed to not answer). Comments are for seeking clarification or suggesting improvements. Your question could use some improvement, by changing each instance of "smart pointer" to "shared pointer". (This is not something we can do for you because such an edit would change the meaning of the question too much. It is up to you, the author, to make this change.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only do allocations like `make_shared`, where the object is allocated next to the control block, you can get rid of `T* ptr` entirely (effectively restricting the address to be directly after the control block):

```cpp
struct alignas(std::alignmax_t) control_block {
    atomic_long shared_count;
    atomic_long weak_count;
};

template<typename T> class ptr {
private: 
    T* get_ptr() const { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(ref+1); }
    control_block* ref;
};
```

This is essentially equivalent to using a `boost::intrusive_ptr`, which also has the overhead of a single pointer.

You could also store the `T*` pointer in the control block.

If you use either of these approaches, only casting to the first base class would be supported, since the pointer is inherently tied to the control block.